# What is the most effective free software to train typing speed on Windows 10 for a user that types 55 WPM?

Tags: windows, gratis

My typing speed is 55 WPM. I type blindly and use all 10 fingers. What's the best free software to train typing and increase my typing speed?

Comment: Audio or Copy typing?

Comment: Normal keyboard typing

Comment: I guess that you are looking at copy typing - if you are composing what you type trainer software has no way of telling when you are thinking rather than looking for a key and no way to tell your accuracy.

Comment: Do not use software for this.It trains man to type while looking at what he types. You need to use papers with text at your left side.

Comment: Once you've reached some speed, it's probably easier to switch to a better keyboard layout than do further highspeed exercise. And if Colemak or Dvorak is still not enough you'll have to use a [chorded keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard) or a chorded keyboard software

Answer (score 1):

[Keybr.com](https://www.keybr.com/) lets you practice touch-typing and keeps track of your statistics. It supports the standard QWERTY keyboard layout plus Dvorak, Workman and others.